# Journey Builder - If I change the time of my automation which sends data in a journey, will the send time of the journey change?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, automation, time

If I change the time of my automation which sends data in a journey, will the send time of the journey change?

Answer (score 0):

We have found a solution for the issue.
The journey was live and we wanted to change time without creating a new version.
Since the automation used a fire event the send time also changed.
We did not have to create a new version for this.